# EOF is not always ^Z on Windows?

Tags: c++, eof, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == EOF)
        cout << x;
    system("pause");
}
```

Inputting the EOF on Windows output nothing. While -1 outputs -1.

Over here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    if ((x=cin.get()) == EOF)
        cout << x;
    system("pause");
}
```

Inputting the EOF on Windows outputs -1. While -1 outputs nothing.

Now I am totally confused 
(I am working on 64-bit Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015; though I do not think this is related)

I also want to add if "x" is assigned EOF in both cases, from where the difference came?
I am comparing the value of "x" to EOF in both cases, right?

Comment: `cin.get()` returns `EOF` if there's no data, so of course that comparison passes. EOF is not a character like you're treating it. If you input EOF, it's not a character read and stored as `EOF`. `EOF` is just a magic number representing a state.

Comment: @chris I dont understand you to be honest :/

If EOF is not caharacter what is assigned to "x" in the first case ? And what in the second case?
Because I am comparing "x" to EOF in both cases right?

Comment: The [input fails](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) in the first case because there's nothing to read (entering EOF ends the data, it isn't data itself) and convert to `int` to store into `x`. However, storing `EOF` into the result wouldn't even work in all cases due to types like pointers that can't store it. You have to check `std::cin`'s flags there. The input [still fails](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) in the second case, but it makes use of the return value to return `EOF`.

Comment: `x` isn't assigned to `EOF` when you use `cin >> x`. `istream::operator>>` doesn't do that when it hits `EOF`. `istream::get` does. They're different functions; they work differently.

Comment: @DrPizza Thanks now I get it (Y).

Comment: @chrisThanks now I get it (Y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EOF` is a macro that expands to a negative int (usually `-1`).

This is a number returned by *some* input functions to indicate that an end-of-file occurred. It is *nothing to do with* the way that the end-of-file condition was triggered by your operating system (be it pressing ^Z, or running out of input, or whatever).

The code:

```
int x;
cin >> x
```

performs *formatted input*.  The `>>` and `<<` operators are for formatted I/O. It means to read a textual representation of a number and convert that to `int`.  The only way you will get `x == -1` is if you actually type in `-1`, as you have found.

To detect whether end-of-file occurred you can inspect the stream via `cin.eof()` after doing the read.  (Note that normally [you should check for all failure modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong), not just end-of-file).

This code:

```
if ((x=cin.get()) == EOF)
```

will match if end-of-file occurred, because `istream::get()` is one of those few functions that indicates an end-of-file condition via the value returned.  Again however, you are outputting the value of the `EOF` macro, which is unrelated to what you did in your operating system to generate the end-of-file condition.